# How to update Mac OS X 10.6.8 to 10.7

Tags: macbook-pro

I have Cienega on my Mac and did a recent update.  Since the update I'm not able to open in Applications Cienega.  I'm receiving a error message that says  I have Mac OS X 10.6.8. The application requires Mac OS X 10.7 or later.  How do I upgrade?

Comment: Is your Mac capable of running Mountain Lion (10.8)?

Comment: Or can your Mac use 10.9 which will be  free upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Apple has started selling [OS X Lion redemption codes](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/D6106ZM/A/os-x-lion),  for £14 (in the UK) so you can still buy the old OS if you need to.

See also: [Is It Possible to Still Upgrade to OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106282/is-it-possible-to-still-upgrade-to-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/106768#106768).

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X Lion (10.7) was removed from the Mac App Store with the release of Mountain Lion in the summer of 2012. Therefore, your only legit option for purchasing a copy would be to look for someone selling a new USB version of the OS (instead of releasing Lion on a DVD, as they had with previous updates, Apple released it on a small USB flash drive). You can try eBay, [they seem to have a few up for grabs](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=mac%20lion%20usb&rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=3). You could find somewhere else to download it, or find a friend who has the USB version and borrow it from them, but that would be illegitimate.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the App Store and find OS X Mountain Lion over there. Click download and run it.

Comment: This won't install 10.7 though...