# Is It Possible To Still Upgrade To OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, upgrade

For those Mac owners still on OS X Snow Leopard, does the possibility exist to upgrade to OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion rather than to 10.9 Mavericks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, Apple sells older OS as redeemable downloads from the web store.**

Apple sells [OS X Mountain Lion redemption codes](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/D6377ZM/A/os-x-mountain-lion), [alongside OS X Lion](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/D6106ZM/A/os-x-lion), for £14 each on the UK store.

The US store link is below and it appears the part number is the same no matter which store you select:

- http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion
- http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion

Answer (score 3):

I have some good news for you. Every Mac running Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) or later will be able to upgrade for free to Mavericks.
[Check the specs page](http://www.apple.com/benl/osx/specs/) on Apple.com

[image]

But if you want to upgrade specific to Mountain Lion (can't think of a reason why?), the answer is no I'm afraid. Every time Apple releases a new OS, they drop support for the older ones.

You can always look on eBay or other second-hand sites to obtain a legal copy of the disk.

**EDIT: Apple offers to buy both [Lion](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion) and [Mountain Lion](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion) in the online Store! Issue solved :)**