# Upgrade from Lion to Mountain Lion but not Mavericks

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have to downgrade from Mavericks to Mountain Lion due to some software required for work. I used the Internet Recovery method to downgrade, but it is not Lion. I would like to upgrade to Mountain Lion, but there is only Mavericks available in the Mac App Store.

Comment: Had you upgraded that machine from Lion to Mountain Lion previously?

Comment: @peisee See my answer to this question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106282/is-it-possible-to-still-upgrade-to-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion

Answer (score 3):

You can purchase OS X Mountain Lion still via Apple online:

[Buy OS X Mountain Lion](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion)

Once you buy it for $19.99 they will send you an App Store link.